# How to add Firebase notification in old Google Play Services library map based project

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, dependencies, firebase-notifications

I am working on old project which is purely based on maps and old google play library 3.2.65 version and now I want to add Firebase notification on the same project unable to resolve Google Play library based conflict.

**Error:Execution failed for task ':ProjectName:processDebugResources'. > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'**

*If you remove old google play library 3.2.65 and add latest google play library then all map based classes get error.*

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that, because the google play library 3.2.65 belongs to Froyo/Gingerbread and [google is going to discontinue the support of them](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html). The minimum version is the 14 (Android 4.0, Ice cream sandwidth)

So you need to update the library up to 10.0.0 or newer.